# USB-C to HDMI adapter continue to use power after Mac goes sleep

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake, hdmi

I use a 3rd-party USB-C to HDMI+USB-A adapter to connect my MacBook Pro to an external display. However, I notice that even after hours I put my Mac to sleep, the adapter still feel warm (but nothing else expect the display is connected), indicating it is still drawing power. Does anyone else also encounter this issue?

P.S. I tried on both MBP 2018 13-inch with 4 TB bolts, and MBP 2021 14-inch with 8 core CPU. They both have this issue. The adapter I use is [Lenovo C120](https://www.4gltemall.com/lenovo-c120-hub.html); there is no power switch on it.